# Tamper proof querystring url value in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, query-string

In my mvc application I have a page which shows query string values
**~(/Device/Devices?pageNumber=1&sortOrder=2&sortBy=DeviceName&recordsPerPage=50&refresh=1)**

As we can see user can easily tamper these values and can do harm. code for this is like

```
@if (Model.HasPreviousPage)  { 

 <a href="@Url.Action("Devices", new { pageNumber = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.SortOrder, sortBy = ViewBag.SortBy, filterBy = ViewBag.FilterBy, ViewBag.FilterValue, recordsPerPage = pageInfo.RecordsPerPage }) ">
```

Here input  fields from user are already enoded and filtervalues from user are  decoded like this

***filterValue =HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Form["SearchString"]);***

So, now my question is how can I make my url tamper proof.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The user can always tamper with the query string.

You have to design your application around the fact that the query string is not secure.

Comment: Atleast these  values  are  not  sensible, but  when  I am  giving  page number as "-1112" by editing the url , app  ui is  crashing. Can I atleast prevent to crash the UI?

Comment: I would just throw an exception on an invalid querystring. If the users modifies it then they have themselves to blame. Just make sure that no harm is done on the server (such as wrong data being displayed or updated).